# VC++ error "no operator << matches these operands", but it works with other compilers

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors

This program doesn't compile in Visual C++, but from some reason it worked with barely any problems when running it with g++ -std=c++11 and an online compiler(of course,when I comment the #include "stdafx.h").

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <istream>
#include <fstream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Hashmap
{
std::multimap<char, string> htmap;

public:
void put(char key, const string value)
{
    pair<char, string> m(key, value);
    this->htmap.insert(pair<char, string>(key, value));
}


int isIn(char c, vector<char> v)
{
    for (auto s : v)
        if (c == s)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

const void get(char key, string word)
{
    int j = word.length();
    vector<char> v;
    vector<char> v2;
    multimap<char, string>::const_iterator Values = this->htmap.find(key);
    int Number = this->htmap.count(key);
    for (int q = 0; q < Number; q++)
    {
        int j = word.length();
        int ok = 1;
        string a = Values->second;
        for (int k = 0; k< word.length(); k++)
            v2.push_back(word[k]);
        for (int i = 0; i< a.length(); ++i)
        {
            if (isIn(a[i], v2) == 1)
                ok = 0;
        }
        v.clear();
        v2.clear();
        if (ok == 1)
        {
            cout << "Word Found: "<< Values->second << endl; // Error Here
        }
        ++Values;
    }
}
void find(const string word)
{
    string s;
    int j = word.length();
    for (int k = 0; k<j; k++)
    {
        char c = word[k];
        this->get(c, word);
    }
}
};

void read(Hashmap t)
{
string key, value;
ifstream f("in.txt");
while (f >> key) // Error Here
{
    for (auto i : key)
        t.put(i, key);
}
string word;
cout << "Word: ";
std::cin >> word; // Error Here
t.find(word);
f.close();
}

int main()
{
    Hashmap t;
    string word;
    read(t);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show the full error message.

Comment: `using namespace std;` got you. Compiles just fine, well two signed/unsigned comparison warnings, without it.

Comment: Just some notes. Don't use using namespace std, this is very error prone. Also use const std::string& word. This is good practice and saves you a lot of ctor calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but from some reason it worked with barely any problems when running it with g++ -std=c++11 and an online compiler ...

I'd suspect you've been missing to

```
#include <string>
```

while using `std::string` extensively in your code.

Always include standard c++ headers corresponding to the classes/functions you are using in your code.

Some compilers will just work with forward declarations of `std::string` in header files like `iostream`, others will actually include the `string` header.

---

Also note:

```
using namespace std;
```

[isn't such a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/14065) in most cases. Better explicitly use the `std::` scope for what you meant to call.

Comment: Zut. Forgot I'd added #include<string> before removing the `using namespace std;`. Both changes were needed to build under VS 2015.